# How to configure opacity based CSS overlay to not effect spacing of surrounding elements?

Tags: html, css, overlay, opacity

Ok, I have the following code: https://jsfiddle.net/7u1aLxaw/

So the issue is that when you hover over an image, it shows an overlay with a name specific to that image. But if the name is longer than the image width, the image immediately to the right is pushed away and the overlay isn't centered on the image. It expands just to the right, not on both sides.

I can't work out how to center the overlay and avoid it effecting divs on either side of it.

*I tried using `display: none`, but I want to preserve the CSS3 transitions. Using `display: none` to completely remove the element removes the CSS3 transition.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `.item_overlay` style to:

```
.item_overlay {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: -95px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
        transition: all 0.3s linear;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
```

Making the position absolute ignores the other elements position, then setting a negative top margin moves it back to the top. http://jsfiddle.net/q8SER/2/

Comment: That did the trick for the spacing between other elements, but any ideas for the centering?

Answer (score 0):

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q8SER/3/

I had to change a whole bunch of stuff to make it work.

First of all, I changed the HTML structure and placed the overlay div before the icon div.

Here is the new overlay CSS:

```
.item_overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Now, because the inner div (overlay) overflows the parent div, I couldn't center it conventionally with auto margins, so I implemented a jQuery solution.

JS code:

```
$(".item_overlay").each( function() {
    var offset = ($(this).parent().width() - $(this).width()) / 2;
    $(this).css("left", offset + "px");
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The issue is that the overlay if often wider than the initial div. So none of the methods you linked to will work. They'll simply crop the overlay if it's too wide.

Comment: You can work around that by setting overflow to visible for the parent div

Comment: And actually, if you don't set the size of the parent div, it should scale with its children.

Comment: Have a quick look at the fiddle in the question, hopefully it shows why the parent can't scale.

Comment: Ok, looks like I misunderstood the question. I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for the help on that. I've trying to avoid using Javascript, so I compromised by floating the overlay to the right, and allowing it to expand left. As this box was to the right of the website, if expanded right it caused the website view to distort as it went off the edge of the screen.